# Rails - how to save text data with Uploadify?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upload, paperclip, uploadify

I have a page, where I can put a text and to this text I would need to add several images. For uploading images I want to use Uploadify.

Now I am solving the problem, that when I choose images and send the form, the data are not sent, only the Uploadify start to transfer files. But the text information are not transferred.

I am doing it this way:

```
%script{:type => "text/javascript"}
  - session_key = Rails.application.config.session_options[:key]
  $(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#file_upload').click(function(event){ 
    event.preventDefault();
  }); 

  $('#file_upload').  ({
    'uploader' : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'cancelImg' : '/assets/uploadify-cancel.png',
    'multi' : true,
    'auto' : false,
    'queueID' : "file_queue",
    'script' : '/users/#{params[:user_id]}/listings',
    'onClearQueue' : true,
    onAllComplete : function(queueData) {
      $('#upload_next').removeClass('disabled');
    },
    'onComplete' : false,
    'scriptData' : {
    '_http_accept': 'application/javascript',
    /'format' : 'json', ?????????????
    '_method': 'post',
    '#{session_key}' : encodeURIComponent('#{u cookies[session_key]}'),
    'authenticity_token': encodeURIComponent('#{u form_authenticity_token}'),
    'text1' : $('#text1').val(),
    'text2' : $('#text2').val(),
    'text3' : $('#text3').val(),
    'text4' : $('#text4').val()
    }
  });

  $('#photo_submit').click(function(event){ 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $('#file_upload').uploadifyUpload(); 
  });   
  });
```

Is there any way to attach these text data to upload? And also, how to make redirect when the upload (all data from form are saved) is done?

Thanks a million times!

Answer (score 0):

This can done by sending your data along with the image using the `formData` attribute in uploadify.

`scriptData` attribute is not in use.

For setting up uploadify with rails you can visit 
http://vignesh.info/blog/rails-4-uploadify-paperclip/